# jQuery UI resizable not working in ie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I downloaded the latest jquery ui and also an older version to test them out, [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/)

I tested the following jquery-ui-1.7.2\jquery-ui-1.7.2\demos\resizable\default.html

and this is not working in any version of ie

also, the latest:

jquery-ui-1.10.3\jquery-ui-1.10.3\demos\resizable\default.html

Is it possible I'm not using the right version(s)? I have seen this demonstrated fine on jsfiddle and it worked fine on ie. where can I get the same files I need to make it work?

here is the code from the example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <style>
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>

<div class="demo-description">
<p>Enable any DOM element to be resizable.  With the cursor grab the right or bottom border and drag to the desired width or height.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it work elsewhere ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek it works on jsfiddle which leads me to believe it works and that i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Check your console. My guess is the path is wrong and cannot load the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i want you to copy and paste following code , and try it on IE , if it works then there was a problem with your files path.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js "></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>

<div class="demo-description">
<p>Enable any DOM element to be resizable.  With the cursor grab the right or bottom border and drag to the desired width or height.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cut and pasted exactly this and opened in ie 10 the re-size is not working.

Comment: because you have to allow activex controls , as the script is remote side

Comment: windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex

Comment: that did it, glad to see that was the problem, it makes me wonder though if I'm going to the trouble to do it this way as opposed to the css3 route which will not work on any version of IE -won't most of my users have the same trouble because their security settings might have been set like mine? IE is really annoying.

Comment: exactly so no one is using it anymore , anyway you can attach css files to same server and it should work normally.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this css link:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```